# Wilma pep proxy and keystone - valid access token not found

Tags: openstack, fiware

I have wilma redirecting valid requests to orion but no messages are reaching it as i always get "Access Token  not found" from wilma. The account entered in wilma config file is the admin account of keystone.
From [openStack API docs](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/api_curl_examples.html)  i request tokens using below request.

```
curl -i \
>   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>   -d '
> { "auth": {
>     "identity": {
>       "methods": ["password"],
>       "password": {
>         "user": {
>           "name": "userAdmin",
>           "domain": { "id": "default" },
>           "password": "pw"
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }' \
>   http://130.206.115.xxx:5000/v3/auth/tokens ; echo
```

I think i get a valid token because direct requests to keystone using curl with x-auth-token work fine.

Then i try to curl from my computer

```
curl --header "X-Auth-Token:$TOKEN" <ipOfWilma>:80/v2/entities
```

And get as a answer: "User token not authorized". 
Wilma reports on console

```
[TOKEN] Checking token with IDM...
User access-token not authorized
Auth-token not found in request header
```

Keystone reports the same

```
"GET /v3/access-tokens/90ecf18114164f98b25668b9a940eb44 HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Why am i getting this access token not found when going through wilma but not for direct requests?

Edit: I also tried requesting domain scoped tokens but received same error.

Comment: When you said "I also tried requesting tokens domain scoped" means that the Domain Scoped request worked or not?

Comment: I got the same error. Edited and clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it. There are 2 things to consider:

1. The error Wilma is returning is `Auth-token not found in request header`, what makes me think that somehow you are not sending well the `--header 'X-Auth-Token: <x-auth-token>'`. Make sure your value is getting parsed well (as I see you use a parameter).
2. The token that you retrieve from Keystone, is a `keystone token`, and not intended for what you need. To access a protected resource, you need to use the `Oauth-token`. It can be a bit confusing in the beginning, but if you think about it, it all makes sense. Check the [Open Specification](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE.OpenSpecification.Security.PEP_Proxy_Generic_Enabler#Main_Interactions) for better understanding.

So, at this point, I'll assume that you already have configured your APP in the Keyrock instance and that you are able to retrieve both the `client_secret` and `client_id`. Now you have 2 ways to retrieve the Oauth Token as stands in the [Fi-ware-Idm wiki](https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm/wiki/Using-the-FIWARE-LAB-instance):

1. [Authorization Code Grant](https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm/wiki/Using-the-FIWARE-LAB-instance#authorization-code-grant). You have a simple example [here](https://github.com/ging/oauth2-example-client), just configure the `config.js` according your requirements.
2. [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://github.com/ging/fi-ware-idm/wiki/Using-the-FIWARE-LAB-instance#resource-owner-password-credentials-grant), which is easier to retrieve for simple requests (in my opinion). For this case we have a simple script in bash [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bitergia/fiware-chanchan-docker/master/images/pep-wilma/4.3.0/auth-token.sh). Just make sure you replace the `CLIENT_ID`, `CLIENT_SECRET`, and the host (or IP) in the `REQUEST` according your requirements. Then, just run:

   ```
   sh auth-token.sh <user-email> <password>
   ```

And then you should be able to retrieve the token. With that token and, if the resource is authorized in the Authzforce, everything should work.

Finally, if you are into `docker` and want to give it a try, we have a workaround using `docker` and `docker-compose` that uses the Generic Enablers you are working with. For example, you can find here the documentation of [PEP Wilma](https://github.com/Bitergia/fiware-chanchan-docker/tree/master/images/pep-wilma) and how to run it (it's very simple).

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Awesome!! Let me know if you still have any doubts :)