# How to add a custom header in outgoing notifications with Orion?

Tags: https, fiware, fiware-orion, custom-headers

I read the "Custom notifications" section in the [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/) and I still have doubts in how to make this work.

Do I have to put in my subscribe POST the following code as a payload?

```
"httpCustom": {
  "url": "http://foo.com/entity/${id}",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
  },
  "method": "PUT",
  "qs": {
    "type": "${type}"
  },
  "payload": "The temperature is ${temperature} degrees"
}
```

How would be a complete payload with a httpCustom for a subscribe with Authentication/Authorization?

Lastly, is really necessary to use [Rush](https://github.com/telefonicaid/Rush), as stated at [Rush Relayer](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/rush/index.html)? In this case, we have to use a "third-party" software that was updated almost 3 years ago. Why not Orion provides this? I would appreciate some help regarding this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `httpCustom` could be used:

```
"httpCustom": {
  "url": "http://example.com/some/path",
  "headers": {
    "X-Auth-Token": "n5u43SunZCGX0AbnD9e8R537eDslLM"
  }
}
```

The token [will expire from time to time](https://ask.fiware.org/question/107/token-duration/). Thus, it should be renewed at a regular interval, modifying the `httpCustom` element with the new token (using `PATCH /v2/subscriptions/<id>` operation, see [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/) for details).

Regarding Rush, it is not necesary if you can achieve the HTTP-to-HTTPS with some equivalent software. Native HTTPS notifications at Orion has been identified as [a topic of interest](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/706) and even there was a [pull request](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/pull/717) with code implementation in that line. Currently it isn't a priority, however contributions related with this are welcomed :)

**EDIT:** the above `httpCustom` configuration will make Orion sending notifications including that `X-Auth-Token` header. Thus, it is supposed that at the `url` endpoint (e.g. `http://example.com/some/path` in the example above) the authentication elements able to process the `X-Auth-Token` header will be listening (typically, a Policy Enforcement Point -PEP- Proxy).

**UPDATE:** since verion 1.7.0, Orion implements native HTTPS notifications (i.e. without needing Rush).

Comment: I will try as soon as possible. While this, @fgalan what do you suggest for DELETE operation be allowed only after authentication/authorization process? I tried to do a DELETE operation passing an X-Auth-Token, but I got this: 
    The status of this operation is: 400 Some error occurred!
    {"error":"BadRequest","description":"Orion accepts no payload for GET/DELETE requests. HTTP header Content-Type is thus forbidden"}

Comment: In order not mixing topics, I'd suggest you ask your new question as an idependent post a stackoverflow, please. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @fgalan . I did what you said, registering some subscriptions with the httpCustom like this:
` "notification": {
   "httpCustom": {
      "url": "http://myapp:1028",
      "headers": {
          "X-Auth-Token": "u2ljrNrf0zNDmITX7Dyyx347DLKa4c"
       }
    } `
But I did not understand how this works. I registered a subscription passing a valid token. When this token will be validated in the moment some notification will be sent? Apparently, the x-auth-token in the httpCustom does not work, because I tested creating a subscription with an invalid token and the notification was sent.

Comment: Orion will not validate the `X-Auth-Token`, but will include it in notifications so others (i.e. the element listening at the URL) can validate. I have edited my original answer in order to make this clearer.

Comment: Answer has been edited, to include relevant information regarding HTTPS notification native support in Orion 1.7.0 (to be released by the beginning of February 2017)

Comment: Very good, @fgalan . I will test it as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @fgalan . Could you help me with the Orion setup for https notifications? We are trying to start the service with -https, -cert and -key params. When we try to test https connection with a curl, we receive "connection refused" message.

Comment: Let's move that new issue to a new question post, in order not mixing with the present one. Could you create a new question post with all the details (i.e. how do you start Orion, which exact command do you use and which result do you get, etc.), using "fiware-orion" label, please? Thanks!